# Vim, sync screen after selecting line

Tags: vim, automation, screen, synchronization

In Vim we can travel to different lines using ':<line-number>'.

And we can also sync the screen by typing 'zt' in normal mode.

But how do we have the screen get synced automatically every time we go to a specific line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by *syncing* you mean centering the line at the top (what `zt` does) / middle / bottom, you can achieve an always-on centering of the current line in the middle via:

```
:set scrolloff=999
```

For all other, I'd recommend a custom `G` mapping:

```
:nnoremap G Gzt
```

To make this also work with `:[N]` and all other jump commands, you'd have to define `:autocmds`, and I would recommend against that.

Comment: ok so its basically not recommended, the reason im asking is because :[number] is somewhat more comfortable than G because during G I cant see the number as I type. But thanks.

Comment: With `:set showcmd`, you do (in the lower right corner). But you have to type quickly, to avoid the timeout. If you prefer, you could define a custom `:[N]G` command; one more letter to type, though.

Comment: and there is no hurry as for some reason there is no timeout. which is better.